# Target System Configurations for running UWP Application

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, system

I just want to know that is there any specific configurations required for the target system to run our **UWP** Application.

Comment: while have .net core?

Comment: Yes it has and it's running. But after some time my application is getting very slow. So I just want to know that is there any configuration problems in the target system.

Comment: why would you think your application getting slow is a problem with the device and not your code?

Comment: When I  Installed my application in one system it's working good. But in some systems after usage of some time it's getting slow. So I got that system configuration doubt. Anyhow I have done some changes and it's working fine now. Thanks for your help @karann

Comment: @Sagar can you share with us, what were the changes that you made which solved this problem for you.

Comment: It's not related to configuration, As like you said it's coding issue. When I am moving from one page to another GC is not clearing the memory. So I have replaced Back Navigation from my project now it's better. Final conclusion is I have replaced Back Button from my project to resolve Memory Leakage Issue in my project. @karann